# Return a pandas DataFrame when using pandas.DataFrame.mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The function `pandas.DataFrame.mean` always returns a `pandas.Series`.  I would like it to return a dataframe with the same column names as the original dataframe.  How does one do this?

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

This returns a pandas.Series object

```
df.mean()
```

so does this

```
df.mean(level = 0)
```

and so does this

```
df.mean(axis = 0)
```

The current way I do this is using the following commands, is this the easiest way to do it?!

```
means = df.mean(axis = 0)
pd.DataFrame(means).T
```

I was hoping for a more straight-forward solution!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do it like this using `to_frame` and transpose:

```
In [188]:
df.mean().to_frame().T

Out[188]:
          a         b         c        d         e
0  0.393221  0.441338  0.445528  0.67516  0.699105
```